# Basic auth not working with POST endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have built a web server that I am trying to password protect. I am trying to set up basic auth using spring boot. This is my configuration file so far:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/", "/v1/occupancy/*")
         .permitAll()
         .anyRequest()
         .authenticated()
         .and()
         .httpBasic();
   }
}
```

This works as expected and protects one of my GET endpoints, allowing me to authenticate.

However, for a POST endpoint, this does not work. The endpoint looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/admin/repository")
public class RepositoryOptionsController {

    private final EstablishmentOptionsRepositoryService establishmentOptionsRepositoryService;
    private final SubAreaOptionsRepositoryService subAreaOptionsRepositoryService;
@PostMapping("/establishment/options")
public ResponseEntity<String> postEstablishmentOption(@RequestBody OptionsRequestDto body) {
```

When I do

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/v1/admin/repository/establishment/options" -u root -v -d "{...}"
```

I get

```
    Enter host password for user 'root':
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'root'
> POST /v1/admin/repository/establishment/options HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic cm9vdDpyb290
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 271
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 271 out of 271 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6E1CBD875597C83E6DEB794986050631; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sun, 27 Sep 2020 15:29:13 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

The same user/pass combination works without issue on GET. What do?

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that CSRF defense is switched on by default for `httpBasic` as well as `formLogin`. Because your `POST` does not contain a CSRF token, Spring Security is rejecting it.

You can get a better idea of this by changing your configuration to permit the `/error` endpoint:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/v1/occupancy/**", "/error").permitAll()
    // ...
```

Then, when you submit a `POST`, you'll see a 403 instead, related to the CSRF token denial.

If your REST API isn't front-facing, then you may be able to switch off CSRF. One way you can do this is by disabling the appropriate endpoints:

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
    // ...
    .and()
  .csrf()
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/v1/admin/repository/establishment/options")
    // ...
```

It if is front-facing, then the appropriate thing to do is [prepare your front-end to hand the CSRF token back to the request](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-csrf).

Answer (score 3):

The configuration require more steps.

1. configure String security

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   ```
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/styles/**",  "/vendors/**", "/node_modules/**",  "/app/**", 
                        "/assets/**", "/api/channel/**", "/jobs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
   ```

   }
2. the implement UserDetailsService
   @Service
   public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
   @Autowired
   UtentiRepostitory utentiRepository;

   ```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nomeUtente) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {

            String userId = nomeUtente;

            Utente utente = utentiRepository.findById(userId).get();

            UserDetailsImp user = new UserDetailsImp(utente);
            user.username = nomeUtente;

            user.password = utente.getPasswd();

            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(nomeUtente);
        }
    }
   ```

   }
   this service that you referenced into Spring Security configuration contains all the roles to generate an object that implements UserDetails interface
3. Implement UserDetails interface

   public class UserDetailsImp implements UserDetails{

   ```
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String password;
    String username;
    public Utente utente;

    public UserDetailsImp(Utente utente) {
        this.utente = utente;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_MENU"));
        return res;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getDenominazione() {
        return utente.getDenominazione();
    }



    public Utente getUtente() {
        return utente;
    }

    public void setUtente(Utente utente) {
        this.utente = utente;
    }
   ```

   }

In my case
@Autowired
UtentiRepostitory utentiRepository;
is a repository that reads data from a user database but you can use any meccanism you like. Now Spring security is set.

Then you need to add a form in the login page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="loginForm" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

Don't gereget to add thymeleaf springsecurity dependency.
I hope this may help