# Basic authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have added basic authentication in my Rest API. My API is CRUD. I have changed the username and password. When I apply the GET, GET by id parameter and POST, they are working flawlessly but when I  call the PUT and DELETE, I get 401 unauthorized. I have checked the username and password for they are correct or no. There is no problem about it. What is the reason about this issue?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.xyztq</groupId>
   <artifactId>TodoApp2</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>TodoApp2</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.project.lombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

SecurityConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
      http.httpBasic();
      http.formLogin();
    
  http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/todos").authenticated().and()
                .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/todos")
                .and().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/todos/{id}").authenticated().and()
                .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/todos/{id}");
        return http.build();
    }
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/todos")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {
    private final TodoService todoService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Todo>> getTodos(@RequestParam(required = false) String title){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todoService.getTodos(title), OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> getTodo(@PathVariable String id){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todoService.getTodoById(id), OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> createTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(todoService.createTodo(todo), OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateTodo(@PathVariable String id,@RequestBody Todo todo){
        todoService.updateTodo(id,todo);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(OK);
    }
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateDoneTodo(@PathVariable String id,@RequestBody Todo todo){
        todoService.patchTodo(id,todo);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteTodo(@PathVariable String id){
        todoService.deleteTodo(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(OK);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090192/basic-auth-not-working-with-post-endpoint  -- might provide some insight

Comment: Thanks but I can only do post request with it. I cannot do put and delete requests.

Comment: @GreenEngineer, if you can do a post request, you can do both put and delete requests as well.